# replacing jQuery click to Keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Current functionality**: I have a button and inside the button there is a text input field. When user enters something in the text input field and click the button. Value from text field is applied to all other empty input field. (or in simple words I have several other text input fields as well where the value from the text field (which is inside the button) is copied).

**Desired functionality**: So instead of clicking the button and then copying the input field to all other text inputs. I am trying to achieve the same functionality using Keyup. So the moment user enters something inside the text field. It will be copied on all other input fields as well.

I tried replacing click event with Keyup but it didn't work. Here is my code

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button applySingles"><input id="applyToAllSingles" type="text" onkeypress="validateInputs(event, 'decimal')"> </a>
```

JS

```
$("a.button.applySingles").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.betSlip.applyToAllSinglesBetInput($(this).find("input").val());
});

BetSlip.prototype.applyToAllSinglesBetInput = function(value) {
    $("#bets div[name=singleBet] .supermid input:text").val(value);
    $("#applyToAllSingles").val(value);
}
```

I am sure that I am missing something since replacing the above function with the below mentioned code doesn't work

```
$("#applyToAllSingles").on("Keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.betSlip.applyToAllSinglesBetInput($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

Comment: just use k not (capital) K in the .on('keyup', ... and it should work if everything else is OK. One thing to check is what $(this) refers to in both cases, initially you were calling $(this) refering to a.button applySingles, now you are refering to #applyToAllSingles so it depends what's the value you wish to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use `keyup` instead of `Keyup`. If everything else is fine, your function should work.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/emisfera/QCcqB/)

Comment: yeah the problem was with capital K in keyup.